# How do i get the HTTP headers in a Google App Engine webapp2 requesthandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-headers

How do i access the http headers of the request that calls this method?

```
class GetDBVersion(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
# writes out db version
```

in main.py

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/version', GetDBVersion
      # and more methods
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this inside the class with webapp2.RequestHandler.

> self.request.headers

It will give you a dict of headers.